# Work with all three pointers in PIC16F877

Tags: assembly, pic

Hello could some one help me of how to use the three pointers in PIC16F877 to work with more than one pointer at same time, "FSR and INDF".

Answer (score 1):

If you will ever read the PIC16F877 datasheet than you can see that is under PIC16F877 MCPU only one indirect addressing register named FSR. An effective 9-bit address is obtained
by concatenating the 8-bit FSR register and the IRP bit (STATUS.7). After initiating the FSR addres you have access to addressed register via INDF register.

Comment: When I read the datasheet I found FSR in each bank, I thought they are separated, So then I recognized that only one FSR in whole managing indirection.  Thank you at all.